# How can I encrypt all ids in url in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5, url-encoding

I need to do all url ids encrypted like :

```
user/edit/1
items/edit/35
posts/details/52
```

to

```
user/edit/sdfjk54dfds
items/edit/sdfjk54dfds
posts/details/sdfjk5s4dfds
```

there is lots of areas like `blade` files and in `controllers` that id used `url('items/edit/2')` and also in controller some function are passed by objects like `public function itemedit(Items $items)`.

I tried  `$encrypt_val = Crypt::encrypt($value)` and `$decrypt_val = Crypt::decrypt($encrypt_val );` but I need to do it everywhere.

There is any short way or Middleware function to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

> Use Laravel Hashids

You can encode id like below

```
$encoded_id = Hashids::encode($id);
```

Your URL will be like below

```
<url>/users/edit/sdfjk54dfds
```

Hash ID installation guide 
https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Uuid` instead of using integer `id`. For this please follow the instruction:

Just create a `trait`:

```
trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });
    }
}
```

and in your model use above trait:

```
use SomeNamespcaeOfTrait;

class User extends Eloquent
 {
    use Uuids;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

and in your migration use `uuid` instead of `integer`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have already database build, so I how can I used it.

Comment: if you are still in development then you can simply follow the above instruction and run php artisan migrate:reset and then  php artisan migrate --step

Comment: My application is already on production. so I can not reset migrations.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called [Laravel HashSlug](https://github.com/balping/laravel-hashslug) that acts as desired. Similarly to the one in sumit's answer, it's built on Hashids, but design specially to work with urls.

Using the above package all you need to do is add a trait and typehint in controller:

```php
class Post extends Model {
    use HasHashSlug;
}
```

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
```

```php
// app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php

public function show(Post $post){
  return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```